# View snapshot not being drawn to screen

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to take a snapshot of a view, and draw it at the top of my `UIScrollView`. Here's the code I have:
*executed in the `viewWillAppear` method

```
        let view = mItemViews[1].getMetaDataContainer()
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        image?.draw(at: mScrollView.frame.origin)
```

However, the image is never drawn to the top of the scrollview. How can I get a snapshot of this view drawn to the top of the scrollview?

Comment: Can you just add a `UIImageView` at the top of the scrollView and then set the screenshot as the image for it?

Comment: @Pierce what `drawRect` method?

Comment: Ignore what I said about `drawRect`, I'm thinking of a regular `UIView`

Comment: @Pierce also, i'm implementing nested sticky headers in a `UIScrollView` that contains `UIStackViews`, so it doesn't seem like adding a static `UIImageView` at the top of the scrollview is going to help much.

Comment: I found this answer, which I think is exactly what you're looking for. It's in Objective C, but the principle is exactly the same, and the code easily translated http://stackoverflow.com/a/14100068/5378116

Comment: @Pierce it's not easily translated if you don't know objective-c, what the code does, or how that code relates to my code